# xltabular error \newline

Tags: errors, line-breaking, xltabular

I am trying to build a table using xltabular. In all 3 columns, I need left aligned text.
In my opinion, the manual of xltabular is not very well documented. I had a look at different topics over here, combining already a lot of usefull tips.

Unfortunately, I still have an error somewhere, but I cannot find it. I do get the right result though. When i put it into Overleaf, it says that I am using a \ (or \newline) at a wrong place.
But I cannot find my mistake...

Could someone please help me out. You can find my MWE below.

Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\hsize=1\hsize\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\hsize=1\hsize\arraybackslash}X|>{\raggedright\hsize=1\hsize\arraybackslash}X|}
\caption{Liste des alarmes possibles}\\
\label{tabelAlarmen}

\hline 
\rowcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{Alarme}&\textbf{Cause}&\textbf{Solution}\\
\hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\textbf{\tablename\ \thetable{}:} Liste des alarmes possibles - Continuation} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{SteelBlue}\textbf{Alarme}&\textbf{Cause}&\textbf{Solution}\\
\hline 
\endhead

\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continuation sur la page suivante\ldots}} \\
\hline
\endfoot

\endlastfoot

COM Error - Arrêt d'urgence - Erreur de communication avec Safety Master L100-81A2 & Problème avec le programme de sécurité  & Vérifiez les connexions des cartes de sécurité du PLC et/ou redémarrez le PLC\\
\hline
FB Error - Arrêt d'urgence - Vérifiez tous les canaux & Au moins 1 FB du programme de sécurité a mal fonctionné. Cette situation se produit si des signaux redondants ne sont pas identiques (par exemple une différence entre les contacts différents de l'arrêt d'urgence, feedback redondant d'une valve de sécurité, \ldots). & Vérifiez les canaux des arrêts d'urgence et d'autres connexions de sécurité.\\
\hline
OUT Erreur - Arrêt d'urgence - Erreur de sortie - Redémarez la machine & Problème avec le programme de sécurité & Vérifiez les connexions des cartes de sécurité du PLC et/ou redémarrez le PLC\\
\hline
Arrêt d'urgence - reset nécessaire & Un arrêt d'urgence a été enfoncé ou le cabinet électrique vient d'être mis sous tension & Appuyez sur le bouton ``Reset''\\
\hline
Erreur EDM Vibreur sortie SIG & Fonctionnement fautif des relais de puissance & Vérifiez le fonctionnement du relais\\
\hline
Erreur EDM Vibreur sortie poumon & Fonctionnement fautif des relais de puissance & Vérifiez le fonctionnement du relais\\
\hline
Arrêt d'urgence - Plateforme peseuse & Arrêt d'urgence a été enfoncé & Déverrouillez le bouton et acquittez l'alarme\\
\hline
Arrêt d'urgence - Secteur vibreur sortie SIG & Arrêt d'urgence a été enfoncé & Déverrouillez le bouton et acquittez l'alarme\\
\hline
Arrêt d'urgence - Secteur Betti & Arrêt d'urgence a été enfoncé & Déverrouillez le bouton et acquittez l'alarme\\
\hline
Arrêt d'urgence - Plateforme poumon & Arrêt d'urgence a été enfoncé & Déverrouillez le bouton et acquittez l'alarme\\
\hline
Interrupteur de fin de course ``poumon vide'' activé: bande du poumon hors la zone de travail & Le détecteur de fin de course est activé & Déplacez la bande du poumon manuellement vers la zone de travail\\
\hline
Interrupteur de fin de course ``poumon plein'' activé: bande du poumon hors la zone de travail & Le détecteur de fin de course est activé & Déplacez la bande du poumon manuellement vers la zone de travail\\
\hline
Pas de communication avec le convertisseur \textit{``x''} & Pas de communication entre le convertisseur et le PLC & Contrôlez les câbles Ethernet\\
\hline
Erreur de communication avec \textit{``élément x du PLC''} & Pas de communication entre la carte du PLC et le CPU & Contrôlez le montage sur le rail DIN ou le fonctionnement de la carte\\
\hline
Erreur convertisseur servo bande à taquets gauche: \textit{``Message du convertisseur''} & Drive en défaut & Appuyez sur le bouton ``Reset''\\
\hline
Erreur convertisseur servo bande à taquets droite: \textit{``Message du convertisseur''} & Drive en défaut & Appuyez sur le bouton ``Reset''\\
\hline
Erreur convertisseur bande élévatrice: \textit{``Message du convertisseur''} & Drive en défaut & Appuyez sur le bouton ``Reset''\\
\hline
Erreur convertisseur bande du poumon: \textit{``Message du convertisseur''} & Drive en défaut & Appuyez sur le bouton ``Reset''\\
\hline
Perte de référence du poumon. Réinitialisez. & Perte de la position de référence du convertisseur & Exécutez le procédé de référence\\
\hline
Perte de référence de la bande à taquets gauche. Réinitialisez. & Perte de la position de référence du convertisseur & Exécutez le procédé de référence\\
\hline
Perte de référence de la bande à taquets droite. Réinitialisez. & Perte de la position de référence du convertisseur & Exécutez le procédé de référence\\
\hline
Niveau maximum de la pile atteint - PROVISION POUMON ARRÊTÉ & Le débit d'entré moyen est plus grand que le débit de sortie moyen & Augmentez la vitesse de production de la cartonneuse ou diminuez la production des SIG\\
\hline
Réhausse du vibreur sortie poumon chargé trop - PROVISION  POUMON ARRÊTÉ & Le débit d'entré moyen est plus grand que le débit de sortie moyen & Augmentez la vitesse de production de la cartonneuse ou diminuez la production des SIG\\
\hline
Poumon complètement rempli - PROVISION POUMON ARRÊTÉ & Le débit d'entré moyen est plus grand que le débit de sortie moyen & Augmentez la vitesse de production de la cartonneuse ou diminuez la production des SIG\\
\hline
Erreur IO-link du disjoncteur électronique & Pas de communication entre le disjoncteur et le IO-link Master & Vérifiez les connexions et le bon fonctionnement du disjoncteur et le IO-link Master\\
\hline
Erreur IO-link du détecteur du niveau de la pile & Pas de communication entre le détecteur et le IO-link Master & Vérifiez les connexions et le bon fonctionnement du détecteur et le IO-link Master\\
\hline
Erreur IO-link du détecteur du niveau de la réhausse & Pas de communication entre le détecteur et le IO-link Master & Vérifiez les connexions et le bon fonctionnement du détecteur et le IO-link Master\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\arraybackslash` as in `\raggedright\arraybackslash`. What't the purpose of `\hsize=1\hsize` here? Also, add a `\\ `after your `\caption`.

Comment: I updated the code with \arraybackslash and the \\ after \cation. This resolves some errors, but not all.
The \hsize=1\hsize is just a general coding I do to have all code the same and make it easier to adjust some basic settings whithout having to look up too much...

I found out the problem is situated in the \label... Apparently, xltabular does not allow application of labels? How could I use them anyway?

Comment: Just put the label inside the caption `\caption{Liste des alarmes possibles\label{tabelAlarmen}}\\ ` . Remember, the longtable and tabularx documentation are also valid for xltabular.